# FMDB query is not taking any effect on the DB

Tags: ios4, fmdb

I am using FMDB in my app to do some updates in my DB. Problem is when I update my table with executeUpdate function, it update my table BUT if I copy the same .sqlite file from project to at another place in my drive and try to query using terminal, it shows that database is not updated, why it is so?

Comment: how about posting your code. It's kinda difficult to know what you are doing with out seeing your code. How about a link to a gihub repository or some place else?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you program will never change the database you copied into your xcode-project. When you compile your program the sqlite database is copied into your app binary. If you would like to examine your resulting database you have to reveal your binary used by the iPhone Simulator.